# Add class to multiple elements in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scope, directive

I am trying to add a class to multiple divs to change it's background color.

HTML:

```
<div class="span6">
    <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>                     
</div>
```

I am currently using this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.heading')).addClass('color-change');
```

My issue is that... there are multiple div's with this heading but it is changing the color of only the first occurrence of that div. How can I have it so all the divs with that class add that css styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector` selects the first element that matches the query. `querySelectorAll` should achieve the result you want.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usw4cozt/

Comment: Although this is answer is correct, it's not how you would do it in Angular

Comment: Agreed, I would rather use `ng-class` or `class={{expression}}` but I won't fault anyone for using native JS, especially if they have some reason they don't want that element bound so strongly to the controller (which they may or may not, idk).

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class instead of class and assign a className to your model :

```
<h1 ng-class='mainCtrl.selectedTheme'>Title 2</h1>

angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)

function MainController() {
  this.selectedTheme = 'blue';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tuavhL2/